# Java gson, ClassCastException on decoding to Map<String,String[]>

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to decode a json string like `{"username":["emmet"]}` to a `Map<String,String[]>` object.

using following code:

```
    String json = "{\"username\":[\"emmet\"]}";
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    Map<String,String[]> map = new HashMap<>();
    map  = (Map<String,String[]>)gson.fromJson(json, map.getClass());
    String[] val = map.get("username");
    System.out.println(val);
```

this exception occurs:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Gson has decoded my object as a `Map<String, ArrayList<String>>` object instead of `Map<String,String[]>` object. How can I force gson to decode my object as `Array` not `ArrayList`?

I'm using `gson-2.8.1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Gson` converts `json` array to a java `List`, so when you trying to get the usernames as `String[]` you getting an `ClassCastException`

If you want to get it as a `String[]` use it that way :

```
    String json = "{\"username\":[\"emmet\"]}";
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map  = (Map<String,List<String>>)gson.fromJson(json, map.getClass());
    List<String> usernames = map.get("username");
    String[] val = usernames.toArray(new String[0]);
    System.out.println(val);
```

That will work for you

Answer (score -1):

You can parse everything out and place it into a Map manually. Here is some code that demonstrates how you could do this

```
String jsonString = "{\"username\":[\"emmet\"]}";
JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject jsonObject = jsonParser.parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();
Set<String> keys = jsonObject.keySet();
Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<>();
for(String key:keys){
    JsonElement jsonElement = jsonObject.get(key);
    if(jsonElement.isJsonArray()){
        JsonArray jsonArray = jsonElement.getAsJsonArray();
        String[] strings = new String[jsonArray.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++){
            strings[i] = jsonArray.get(i).getAsString();
        }
        map.put(key, strings);
    } else {
        //Handle other instances such as JsonObject, JsonNull, and JsonPrimitive
    }
}
```