# Why does Gson allow normal array declaration, then throw ClassCastException when accessing it in a Map?

Tags: arrays, json, kotlin, gson, classcastexception

When [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) is used to convert a JSON map to a Kotlin/Java Map, and the JSON values contain arrays as `"[]"`, there will be a `ClassCastException` error if `Array<T>` is declared and then accessed. (`Array<T>` is equivalent to Java array `T[]`):

app/build.gradle:

```js
dependencies {
   ...
   implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
}
```

JsonConverter.kt (using [this guide](https://www.baeldung.com/gson-json-to-map)):

```kotlin
@Throws(JsonSyntaxException::class)
fun gsonMapTest() {
    val jsonInput = """
        {"keyOne":[],"keyTwo":["valueA"],"keyThree":[]}
    """.trimIndent()

    // Guidance: https://www.baeldung.com/gson-json-to-map
    val jsonMap1 = Gson().fromJson<LinkedTreeMap<String, Array<String>>>(jsonInput, MutableMap::class.java)
    val jsonMap2: Map<*,*> = Gson().fromJson(jsonInput, Map::class.java) // MutableMap can also be used

    // These work fine
    val firstKeyInMap1: String = jsonMap1.keys.first() // returns String
    val firstKeyInMap2 = jsonMap2.keys.first() // returns String

    // Errors here: "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;"
    val firstValueInMap1: Array<String> = jsonMap1.values.first()
    val firstValueInMap2: Array<String> = jsonMap2.values.first() as Array<String>
}
```

This error happens at runtime:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
```

But the Map objects are allowed to be created, without any warning or error. It's only when a Map value is accessed that the error occurs.

From the error message, I initially thought that the call to `jsonMap1.values.first()` was trying to cast the empty array to a String. I eventually figured out that the `"[L"` in the error message means ["array of Objects"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085889/l-array-notation-where-does-it-come-from)

**If the declarations in the code sample are changed from `Array<String>` to `ArrayList<String>` then it all works fine.**

**So my questions are:**

- Is it normal behavior for Gson to allow `Array<T>` declaration, but cause an error when the item is accessed?
- Is there a way to show a warning or compile error to say that `ArrayList<String>` should be used instead of `Array<String>`?

---

I checked the Github Issues for Gson. I couldn't find this issue reported, but I found some slightly similar ones:

- https://github.com/google/gson/issues/105 -- ClassCastException thrown instead of ParseError
- https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1107 -- Gson deserializes wildcards to LinkedHashMap
- https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1247 -- Confusing Exceptions

Update: Perhaps this is the same problem?: [Java gson, ClassCastException on decoding to Map<String,String[]>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47889531/java-gson-classcastexception-on-decoding-to-mapstring-string)

Comment: You have to specify a concrete _parameterized type_ to deserialize to (typically done with `TypeToken`). Your current example is not working as it might be supposed to because `MutableMap` you're passing is not parameterized (defaults to `<Object, Object>` thus Gson chooses what to deserialize to: `String` and `Collection<...>`). This is because the `Gson.fromType(..., Type)` method has a design flaw for automatic casting to _any_ type regardless what `Type` is (except of the overload with `Class<T>` that leverages the issue a bit down), therefore you probably can't have a warning there.

Comment: Due to the generics erasure in Java you can cheat `javac` (and probably `kotlinc`, right?), and this is what actually happens unless you **access** the object (and this is related to the flaw in that method). BTW, the arrays you are talking about are not primitive.

Comment: @fluffy You've written some great comments that are very useful and detailed. Please consider converting them to a proper answer. And, yes, you were right about the arrays not being primitive - I've corrected the description of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by user *fluffy* in his/her comments, one must use a `TypeToken` to deserialize a parameterized Generics type, in addition to the Generics delcaration. However, it does not seem to be needed for `ArrayList<String>`:

```kotlin
@Test
@Throws(JsonSyntaxException::class)
fun gsonMapTest() {
    val jsonInput = """
    {"keyOne":[],"keyTwo":["valueA"],"keyThree":[]}
    """.trimIndent()

    // Guidance: https://www.baeldung.com/gson-json-to-map
    val jsonMap1 = Gson().fromJson<LinkedTreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>>>(jsonInput, MutableMap::class.java)

    val listType = object : TypeToken<LinkedTreeMap<String, Array<String>>>() {}.type
    val jsonMap2: Map<*,*> = Gson().fromJson(jsonInput, listType) // MutableMap can also be used

    // These work fine
    val firstKeyInMap1: String = jsonMap1.keys.first() // returns String "keyOne"
    val firstKeyInMap2 = jsonMap2.keys.first() // returns String "keyOne"

    // No longer errors here
    val firstValueInMap1: ArrayList<String> = jsonMap1.values.first() // returns empty list
    val firstValueInMap2: Array<String> = jsonMap2.values.first() as Array<String> // returns empty array
}
```